# Recursive query to select Parent and Child cases in sql

Tags: sql, common-table-expression

I'm trying to implement recursion on query using Common Table Expression. However I'm not very much familiar with it. The scenario surrounds between parent and child cases where Parent when logged in can see his own as well as his all children cases and so on and so forth. But I'm unable to do this with using cte expression.

I have a user table and a relation table that contains both the primary and secondary user. The primary user is parent and secondary user is child.

Below is my query.

```
select *
from dbo.[Case] c
left join dbo.[User] u on c.AssignedTo = u.UserId
left join dbo.[User] uu on c.AssignedTo = uu.UserId
where uu.UserId in (select SecondaryUser from  dbo.[Relations]
                    where PrimaryUser = 'f422233f-9c70-4052-81a5-e2525707df0b') 
    or u.UserId = 'f422233f-9c70-4052-81a5-e2525707df0b'
```

But the above query only returns one parent and one child case. And i want to have multiple parents and their multiple child case using common table expression.

Assuming some users as follows

```
    Id   Name   Email 
    001  Salar  salar@gmail.com
    002  Ather  ather@gmail.com
    003  John   john@gmail.com
```

And In RelationShip Table

```
Id   PrimaryUser SecondaryUser
101    001       002
001    002       003
```

And their Assigned Cases

```
Id     CaseTitle    CaseDescription  AssingedTo
101    Case 1       First case    001
102    Case 2       Second case   002
103    Case 3       Third case    003
```

So when i logged in to 001 id I should see all three cases, and when i logged in with 002 i should see last two cases.

Comment: Please provide sample data and desired results.

Comment: Please see the edited questions @GordonLinoff

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This query will return all user ids in relation to first id. You can join result with cases:

```
declare @Users as table
    (UserId  int)
;

declare @Relations as table
    (PrimaryUser  int, SecondaryUser int)
;    

INSERT INTO @Relations
    (PrimaryUser, SecondaryUser)
VALUES
    (1,2),
    (1,3),
    (2,4),
    (2,7),
    (2,8),
    (5,6),
    (6,19)

INSERT INTO @Users
    (UserId)
VALUES
    (1),
    (2),
    (3),
    (4),
    (5),
    (7),
    (5),
    (6),
    (19),
    (20)

;WITH cte1 AS (
  SELECT UserId AS [User]
  FROM @Users 
  WHERE UserId = 5
  GROUP BY UserId
UNION ALL  
  SELECT SecondaryUser  AS [User]
  FROM cte1
  JOIN @Relations t 
    ON t.PrimaryUser = cte1.[User]   
)
SELECT [User] FROM cte1
```

Comment: Thanks @Tomasz. How can i now use case table in cte?

Comment: In last select you can join with cases table: SELECT * FROM cte1
INNER JOIN dbo.[Case] c on c.AssignedTo = [User]

Answer (score 0):

Here is a very simple example of a hierarchical CTE:

```
with t(level,path,boss,name) as 
(
        -- this is the starting point (can be one or more records)
        select 0,name,boss,name from @empl where boss is null

        union all

        -- here you construct the tree (via the join conditions)
        select
            level + 1,
            path + ' > ' + e.name,
            e.boss, e.name 
        from @empl e
            inner join t on e.boss = t.name                
) 
-- here you collect the results from the cte
select * 
from t 
order by path;
```

Cf. https://gist.github.com/pedroreys/8336d6f4dcb63ba619c0